# How to get the title of webpage using QtWebEngine

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am building a simple web browser application using pyqt and Python. I want to get the title of the current web page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I just used this:

```
self.browser.page().title()
```

`self.browser` is QWebEngineView(). When using this use it like:

```
self.browser.loadFinished.connect(# Do something)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the title of the current web page then you must use the title() method or the titleChanged() signal:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, stretch=0)
        lay.addWidget(self.view, stretch=1)

        self.view.titleChanged.connect(self.label.setText)
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.qt.io"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```